# Command to Install binaries in CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

Before I can `find_package` dependent libraries, I need to install them on my system. I have seen options to add external dependencies through `ExternalProject_Add` by downloading the source code and compiling them. But what if there are binaries available? How can I download them with `cmake`?

Comment: "But what if there are binaries available? How can I download them with cmake?" - You could download them like any other files. E.g. with [file(DOWNLOAD)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download).

Comment: what about using 
`execute_process(
    COMMAND "apt-get install pkg-name"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE msg_output
    ERROR_VARIABLE error
  )`

Comment: I tried `execute_process`. It does not give me any error, but when I `dpkg -l | grep pkg-name`, I don't see the package.

Comment: `COMMAND "apt-get install pkg-name"` is definitely wrong: command name and arguments should be represented by **separate parameters**.

Comment: I mean `set(command "apt-get" "install" "-y" "pkg-name")`. This works for me. Is this a hack or a proper way to do it?

Comment: Why do you think about it as a "hack"? For me, calling `apt` from the configuration of the project looks somehow unusual. Also, such `apt` call works only for a user with administrative privileges, but CMake projects are usually configured by a regular user. Anyway, you (as a project's developer) are free to do anything what do you need.

Comment: "hack" because of the reasons you gave actually :)